# Formula for percentage: (0% = 400) x% = 835 (100% = 1700) What is formula for x?

Tags: statistics

Im stuck on a mathematical problem while programming.

Im making a progress bar, that says how far the user is to the next level.

Lets say that the number **400** is the start of that level, and it ends at **1700**. What formula can I use to get the percentage if the user is at **835**?

Info:

400 = 0%;

835 = ?% (*this is the value that is inbetween 0% and 100%*) This is what I need a formula for.

1700 = 100%;

and what is this type of mathematics called?

Comment: $\frac{835-400}{1700-400}\times 100$%.

Comment: This sort of calculation is called linear interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

This called linear interpolation 
$$\frac{100-0}{1700-400}=\frac{y-0}{835-400}$$
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this convex combination to interpolate the values:
$$
v = (1-p) \, v_1 + p \, v_2
$$
where $p$ is the percentage between $0=0\%$ and $1=100\%$.

In this case:
$$
v = (1-p) \, 400 + p \, 1700
$$

If you solve for $p$:
$$
v = 400 + p (1700 - 400) = 400 + p \, 1300
$$
we get
$$
p = \frac{v - 400}{1300}
$$
The percentage $p$ for the value $v=835$ is:
$$
p= \frac{835-400}{1300} = 0.335 = 33.5 \%
$$